# does HTML5 support any kind of polygonal masking?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm curious if it's possible (either with canvas or with CSS) to place a mask over a JPG or PNG to make some part of it transparent.  Specifically, I want to define a circle over the image, and for the pixels within that circle to stay opaque, but for all the other parts of the image to become transparent.

I'm Java this is a fairly straight forward operation, but I'm not finding any analog in Javascript and am wondering if this is simply not possible.

TIA

Comment: not sure about masking you could do it with canvas, and just render what would be in the circle.

Comment: @nycynik—I think you can do the opposite with canvas too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check this [-webkit-mask tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-image-wipes/) from css tricks.

**CSS**

```
.circle-mask {
    -webkit-mask-box-image: url(mask.png);
}
```

RESULT

[image: CSS MASK]

Related links:

- [CSS3 -webkit-mask property.](http://blog.romanliutikov.com/coding/css3-webkit-mask-property/)
- [Using an Image as a Mask](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Masks/Masks.html)
- [-webkit-mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-webkit-mask-image)

Comment: I assume this only works in Webkit browsers. Has this a chance to be included in the official HTML5 specifications?

Comment: @Philipp modern specifications reflects properties usage, so if most of developers will use  this property, it will be included to specification

Comment: I like this answer, but I do think I'm going to go with the Canvas option for now, given that that's a lot more universal in modern day browsers.  Obviously this approach is a ton more intuitive, but until other browsers adopt it, it's kind of a nonstarter.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel if it is not critical feature, check this excellent [jeffrey way's comment](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-image-wipes/#comment-86837): *‘As long as you can provide a suitable fallback for older browsers, it’s 100% practical. It’s funny how we’re fine with unique viewing experiences for mobile users, or iPad users…but not for old IE users.’*

Comment: @VladimirStarkov, I agree that in many instances this would be true, however in the situation I have, the masked shape of the image is really integral to the graphic design... it's not just an embellishment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SVG filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html) to create something like a »blend mode«. You can use i.e. Inkscape to compose these effects. If you become familiar with the syntax you can create a lot of effects. Perhaps you can post an image of the desired effect, than it should be more easy to see what can be done. There are also some js libraries to make certain effects with images.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [mask](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#Masking) tag from SVG, to actually place images of circles with different gradients, do tell if this helps?